# Parallelizing access to S3 objects in Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing a Scala program to read objects matching a certain `prefix` on S3.

At the moment, I'm testing it on my Macbook Pro and it takes 270ms (avg. over 1000 trials) to hit S3, retrieve the 10 objects (avg. size of object 150Kb) and process it to print the output.

Here's my code:

```
val myBucket = "my-test-bucket"
val myPrefix = "t"
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() 

//Can I make listObject parallel?
val listObjRequest: ListObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(myBucket)
val listObjResult: Seq[String] = s3.listObjects(listObjRequest).getObjectSummaries.par.toIndexedSeq.map(_.getKey).filter(_ matches s"./.*${myPrefix}.*/*")

//Can I make forEach parallel? 
listObjResult foreach println //Could be any function

println(s"Total time: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}ms")
```

In the big scheme of things, I've got to sift through 50Gb of data (approx. 350K nested objects) and delete objects following a certain prefix (approx. 40K objects).

Hardware considerations aside, what can I do to optimize my code?

Thanks!

Comment: For a pure Scala solution, use `Future`s. You could also consider using Apache Spark.

Comment: S3 supports [batch deletion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html). Since you're IO bound anyway for this task, I'd look into that to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to batch the request objects and send a request for batch deletion in S3. You can group the objects to delete and then parallalize the mapping over the parallel collection:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{DeleteObjectsRequest, DeleteObjectsResult}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util.Try

object AmazonBatchDeletion {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val filesToDelete: List[String] = ???
    val numOfGroups: Int = ???

    val deletionAttempts: Iterator[Future[Try[DeleteObjectsResult]]] =
      filesToDelete
       .grouped(numOfGroups)
       .map(groupToDelete => Future {
          blocking {
            deleteFilesInBatch(groupToDelete, "bucketName")  
          }
        })

    val result: Future[Iterator[Try[DeleteObjectsResult]]] = 
      Future.sequence(deletionAttempts)

    // TODO: make sure deletion was successful.
    // Recover if needed form faulted futures.
  }

  def deleteFilesInBatch(filesToDelete: List[String], 
                         bucketName: String): Try[DeleteObjectsResult] = {
    val amazonClient = new AmazonS3Client()

    val deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName)
    deleteObjectsRequest.setKeys(filesToDelete.map(new KeyVersion(_)).asJava)

    Try {
      amazonClient.deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `grouped(3)`? You can delete up to 1000 items in a single call according to AWS Java SDK documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html

Comment: And one more thing: the S3 client is synchronous and blocking. You need to bring a thread pool of appropriate size to run your computations on, if you need to have any visible effect from parallelization.

Comment: @Haspemulator The `ParSeq` should utilise a `ForkJoinTask` with an underlying `ForkJoinThreadPool`. Do you see a need for anything else? As for `grouped(3)` that is for the sake of the example.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. `ForkJoinThreadPool` is absolutely unsuitable for synchronous and blocking tasks, unless you wrap your synchronous code in `blocking` block, which parallel collection probably won't do for you. I think you'd be better off with `Future.traverse` and custom executor.

Comment: As for batch size in your example, I'm personally a proponent of examples which are safe to just paste in your code. It's not a secret people copy and paste code from StackOverflow into their programs without checking it, so we'll do community a good service by providing examples which will be most useful when directly pasted.

Comment: @Haspemulator Ahh, I see what you mean. That might be a better idea indeed. Regarding the copy and paste example, I have to disagree here. Anyone taking ownership of code I answer on StackOverflow should make sure it works for his/her case without blindly believing "this magic just works".

Comment: Firstly, thank you guys for this discussion! I was more of the opinion to do the process handling for objects I receive in batches. That way I do not have to hold on to all the data at once as suggested in `filesToDelete` as it might be a couple of GBs and might not be optimal.

Comment: I've tried my own code with `mutable.ParSeq` and `immutable.ParSeq` both had a higher processing time on average; 300ms and 315ms respectively.

Comment: @AngryPanda Did you also try the code I suggested above? My first suggestion used `ParSeq`, but after the discussion I thought it would be a good thing to post a more "correct" alternative.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: testing it now. Thanks

Comment: This resolves my problem: http://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/forkjoin-framework-tutorial-forkjoinpool-example/

Comment: @AngryPanda A for join model is exactly what my answer tries to convey.